# How can I get Apache SSL to work in 13.10 after upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, apache2, 13.10, shm, mod-ssl

I've just upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04 and my Apache config won't load. I get this error:

```
AH00526 Syntax error on line 43 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:
SSLSessionCache: 'shmcb' session cache not supported (known names: ) Maybe you
need to load the appropriate socache module (mod_socache_shmcb?).
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I can't seem to find a package for it, and it seems it [used to be provided by the apache2-bin package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/apache2-bin/filelist). I can't seem to find `mod_socache_shmcb` on my system anywhere either. I'm running apache2-2.4.6-2ubuntu on amd64. How can I get SSL to work again for multiple virtual hosts?

The `shmcb socache` module seems to be [there still in 2.4 according to the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_socache_shmcb.html).

Comment: I was mistaken, the module is actually there. See my answer below to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Enable the module by copying the file:

```
cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/socache_shmcb.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

That will handle the first error.

Then there is an error about `SSLMutex`, so replace that line of mods-enabled/ssl.load with
[this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969272/apache-sslmutex-issue):

```
Mutex sysvsem default
```

Comment: I've since learned of `a2enmod` to enable modules, but it is not always available.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to enable and disable Apache modules on Ubuntu is via the `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` commands. In this case:

```
sudo a2enmod socache_shmcb
sudo service apache2 restart
```